# Look to get number using regex from string

Tags: c#, regex, string

Looking for a regex to get the number from a string.

My string could be:

```
abcd1
abcd01
abcd11
```

I tried this but it is not working: `/\d+$/` and some others but they are not seems to be correct.

Is there any easy way to get the number from a string? ANd it will be at the end.

Comment: Why the slashes at the beginning and the end? C# is not JavaScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you want this regex (without the beginning slashes as C# does not need that)

```
\d+$
```

To ignore leading 0

[1-9]\d*$

If you want to drop ALL leading 0's, it honestly would be easier to just cast your result to an `Int32`

Comment: I just tested and it is giving me the result except for this abcd01. Is there anyway to just get 1 instead of 01?

Comment: @alice7 use `(0|[1-9]\d*)$` then

Comment: Hamlet is ALMOST right if you want to ignore the leading 0's: [1-9]\d*$

Comment: @alice7 do you just want to drop leading zeros, or do you only want the last number?  In your example above of `abcd11` do you want `1` or `11`?

Comment: @Esailija: thanks it works. I tested with all the above and it works.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is that you want. "Is there anyway to just get 1 instead of 01?" Yes, there is.

```
[1-9]\d*$
```

Comment: Your answer will force two digits, change the + to a * and this will work

Comment: @Esailija You are right, that will only catch one leading 0. I updated my answer